# Issues with newline character while using ansi-term in emacs

Tags: shell, emacs, terminal, tcsh, ansi-term

I am trying to use ansi-term in emacs (configured to tcsh shell). I see some issues with newline characters being displayed. If I try the following from the terminal (ansi-term), I get the correct output:

```
myterm > echo "Line1"; echo "Line2"; echo "Line3";    
Line1
Line2
Line3
myterm >
```

But if I try putting the same lines in a shell script and try to execute the script from ansi-term, I get a wrong output

Script: (test)

```
#!/usr/bin/env tcsh
echo "Line1"; echo "Line2"; echo "Line3";
```

Running the script (test):

```
myterm > ./test
Line1
     Line2
          Line3
               myterm >
```

Note: /usr/bin/env tcsh does point to the correct shell (its the same shell that I used while invoking ansi-term). Also executing the script from gnome-terminal also displays the correct output.
I have also tried setting the following variables but it did not solve my issues:

```
(set-terminal-coding-system 'utf-8-unix)
(setq default-process-coding-system '((utf-8-unix . utf-8-unix)))
```

Comment: most likely \r & \r\n difference. can't reproduce here, so can't help more.

Comment: the output of `infocmp` might help to generate some answers here

Comment: Try use `printf` instead of `echo` and specify \r\n explicitly at the end of each string

Comment: @Ivan : Using printf with \r\n will give me the required output in this case. But the problem is that I can't control the outputs of the tools I use. The  prints from those tools have the same issue. The above code is the simplest example which replicates the issue.

Comment: @user6170930: I'm not sure how to use infocmp. Could you give me some more details?

Comment: The [infocmp](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/infocmp1.html) utility, executed without any options, will produce the terminfo description of the currently defined terminal in a form suitable for editing and recompilation with the tic utility. I was curious whether a `cr=^J` in your eterm-color terminfo description might be the problem, but when I changed mine in an attempt to replicate your problem ansi-term didn't change its behaviour. so now I'm as confused as yourself.

Comment: ok. I think your problem is the `opost` option to `stty`.  I can emulate your problem by setting `stty -opost` which tells my terminal not to post-process output data. So `stty +opost` might be what you need.

Comment: oops: i should have said `stty opost` not `stty +opost`

Comment: @user6170930 I tried that but it still didn't work. my ssty - a output is as follows: speed 38400 baud; rows 50; columns 93; line = 0;
intr = ^C; quit = ^\; erase = ^?; kill = ^U; eof = ^D; eol = <undef>; eol2 = <undef>;
swtch = <undef>; start = ^Q; stop = ^S; susp = ^Z; rprnt = ^R; werase = ^W; lnext = ^V;
flush = ^O; min = 1; time = 0;

Comment: -parenb -parodd cs8 -hupcl -cstopb cread -clocal -crtscts
-ignbrk brkint ignpar -parmrk -inpck -istrip -inlcr -igncr icrnl ixon -ixoff -iuclc -ixany
imaxbel -iutf8
opost -olcuc -ocrnl onlcr -onocr -onlret -ofill -ofdel nl0 cr0 tab3 bs0 vt0 ff0
isig icanon iexten echo echoe echok -echonl -noflsh -xcase -tostop -echoprt echoctl echoke

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111048/discussion-between-user6170930-and-pulimon).

Comment: moved this to chat because SO is complaining about too many comments.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you set `stty onlcr` in your script, you will get the behaviour you require.
Translating the command into english one might say:
 **s**et the **tty** to **o**utput **n**ew**l**ine as **c**arriage-**r**eturn and newline.

This is a workaround of course, because this option should be set by default. I can see from the output of `stty -a` that you gave in your comments that it *is* set in the tcsh that runs in your ansi-term. I suspect one possible reason why ansi-term and your shell script behave differently is due to the following lines in term.el

```
    (apply 'start-process name buffer
       "/bin/sh" "-c"
       (format "stty -nl echo rows %d columns %d sane 2>/dev/null; 
                if [ $1 = .. ]; then shift; fi; exec \"$@\""
               term-height term-width)
       ".."
       command switches)))
```

The `stty` command in the above actually sets `onlcr` twice, since
 the compound option `-nl` translates to  `icrnl -inlcr -igncr onlcr -ocrnl -onlret`
and  the `sane` option translates to
`cread -ignbrk brkint -inlcr -igncr icrnl -iutf8 -ixoff -iuclc -ixany imaxbel opost -olcuc -ocrnl onlcr -onocr -onlret -ofill -ofdel nl0 cr0 tab0 bs0 vt0 ff0 isig icanon iexten echo echoe echok -echonl -noflsh -xcase -tostop -echoprt echoctl echoke`

Another possible cause: for non-login shells tcsh will *only* read `/etc/csh.cshrc` and either `~/.tcshrc` or `~/.cshrc` when it starts up, but for login shells it reads a number of other files including `/etc/csh.login` `~/.history` or the value of `$histfile` - You should consult the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/csh) for full details including the exact order in which it reads things.

Comment: @[pulimon](http://stackoverflow.com/users/990772/pulimon) I did a major re-write of the answer since my first go was a little terse. There is a discussion about it on [meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/322563/editing-my-answer-that-has-been-upvoted-accepted-and-has-bounty-paid)